# Codeigniter content fetched each X seconds

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, real-time

I have a Codeigniter framework vote app, I want to add a new feature in the homepage, update every X seconds the homepage, I already prepared the SQL query to return the items votes with item ID, and Codeigniter will serve it JSON format.

Front-end I'm working with angularjs, what is the best method to auto fetch the JSON content each X seconds.

Comment: $timeout/$interval call to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the $interval and $http functions since you're using angular.

It would look something like this:

```
// Set the time (in milliseconds)
var time = 1000;
// Call this in your controller
function($scope, $interval, $http) {
  // Start the interval
  $interval(function() {
    // Send a GET request to your URL
    $http.get('/my/url', { params: {} }).success(function(data) {
      // Add the new JSON data to current scope
      $scope.json_content = data.json_content;
    });
  }, time);
};
```